# R: summarise by ID only when the same ID repeat twice but don't summarise if it repeats more then twice

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I'm trying to summarise a dataframe by ID but I would like to summarise only when the same ID repeats in two rows and not summarise when the same ID repeats in more than two rows.
I have tried:

`df %>% group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::summarize_if(n() == 2, first)`,

but Im getting an error says: "Error in `n()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs."

tnx for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2), val=1:5)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(val = if (n() == 2L) first(val) else val) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#      id   val
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     3
# 3     2     4
# 4     2     5
```

You shouldn't use `summarize_if` here for two reasons:

1. It's been superseded, preferring `summarize(across(...))`, with or without the use of `dplyr::where`; and
2. The `_if` variant chooses the columns to summarize, not the rows.

To use the `across(..)` variant for multiple columns, we can do this:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ if (n() == 2L) first(.) else .)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: thank u! it was really helpful but created data frame contains only one column-the id column, how can I summarise all columns?
I also couldn't make the across variant u suggested, I'm getting a long error:
Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(everything(), ~if (n() == 2L) first(.))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 730: ID = NA.
Caused by error in `across()`:
Caused by error in `dplyr_internal_error()`:
Backtrace:
  1. mess_data_duoble %>% group_by(ID) %>% ...
 11. dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error("dplyr:::summarise_mixed_null", `<named list>`)

Comment: If you ran anything close to the fake data I provided, it is not feasible (in any way I can imagine) to produce only a single column, `summarize` will at a minimum keep the one column (and all if using `across(everything(), ...)`). Since it works perfectly with my sample data, perhaps you should provide a sample of your own data? Please with at least one example each of "2" and "> 2" rows per group so that we can clearly see the difference you are expecting. We don't need dozens of columns, perhaps a few (other than the grouping column(s)) should suffice.

Comment: BTW, if you did just `across(everything(), ~if (n() == 2L) first(.))`, then you didn't try my code. By not having an `else` clause, the `if` statement assigns `NULL` to that column, and that will (obviously) fail. The use of `else` here is not optional; the only time I think it might be optional is if you were working on a list-column (which I am not showing nor suggesting).

Comment: but the code with ```else``` shows a syntax error... :(

Comment: It doesn't error with my data. You haven't shared your data. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on how to make the question _reproducible_ by sharing data. Best of the bunch is the use of `dput`, `data.frame`, or `read.table`, so that we can work with the same type of data you're working with. We don't need a lot, just enough rows and columns to get the point across.

Comment: If someone else using it- in my R Studio it shows a syntax error but worked perfectly with the error.. #r2evans tnxxxxx